# Which framework for receiving many HTTP Post requests?

Tags: java, spring, http

I'll be receiving many `HTTP POST` request, let's assume at least 50 per minute, 24/7. I have no control over how these requests are transmitted, so I'm tied to http post here.

Which framework could I best use for receiving these many post requests? Does `Spring` offer a framework for handling POST push messages?

Comment: Note that 50 requests per minute is trivial. There are a number of good frameworks (including Spring MVC, my personal choice), but recommendation questions are specifically off-topic.

Comment: Note that a server receives the requests, not the framework you use. The framework may do some request processing as the result of the server receiving the requests and if you write code that eats up 50% CPU time for no reason, things won't work well. The point being that this is more related to what server software you use and what hardware you run it on - it is going to work fine on a decent computer with proper network configuration, its going to work considerably less fine on a Raspberry PI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the danger of sounding arrogant, it seems that 50 request per minute, i.e. less than one request per second, is not so many. Of course, it does depend on what the processing of the requests entails.

Spring does offer the Spring WebMVC framework (see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) which will most likely help you very well to achieve your task.

You"ll have to create a Controller and annotate one of the methods to handle POST requests, something like this (adapted from the Spring docs):

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/YourPath")
public class YourController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processThePost(...many options to receive params from the request...) {

        // process the parameters

        return "redirect:/someFrontEndServlet";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

is is a REST POST? you could try Jersey for this https://jersey.java.net/ and my favorite tutorial is this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html